# Extending a probability measure on a manifold to the ambient space

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, differential-geometry

Let $\pi$ be a probability measure defined on $(\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{M}))$, where $\mathcal{M}$ is a smooth manifold and $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{M})$ is the Borel sigma-algebra on it. Let $\mathcal{C} \supset \mathcal{M}$ be a set.

> 1. Can I always extend $\pi$ onto $(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{C}))$?
> 2. If not, what conditions on the set $\mathcal{C}$ do I need to be able to extend $\pi$?

Comment: For context, here the manifold arises as the fiber of a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ where $n > m$. That is, assuming $0$ is a regular value of $f$
$$
\mathcal{M} := \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\, f(x) = 0\right\}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As clarified in your comment, your manifold is the level-set of a smooth hence continuous hence measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. So the manifold is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. You can extend $\pi$ to all $\pi^*$ on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by letting $\pi^*(A)=\pi(A\cap\mathcal{M})$. If $\mathcal{C}$ itself is measurable, the restriction of $\pi^*$ to $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{C})$ does the job. If $C$ is not measurable, you can take the measure to be $\pi^{**}$ with $\pi^{**}(A)$ being the $\pi^*$-outer measure of $A\cap C$. That this still defines a suitable measure is shown, for example, in 214A of the second volume of [Fremlin's treatise](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm).

Comment: Thank you! If you don't mind, can you give some more references about $\pi^*(A):= \pi(A\cap \mathcal{M})$? Does it have a name?

Comment: Fremlin uses the term "subspace measure."

Comment: I found the concept of a trace. Given the measurable space $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ and a subset $\mathcal{M}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ we call the trace of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ on $\mathcal{M}$ the set
$$
\text{trace}_{\mathcal{M}}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)):=\left\{A\cap \mathcal{M}\,:\, A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\right\}.
$$
Then in Cinlar's book he shows that $\text{trace}_{\mathcal{M}}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ is a sigma-algebra over $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: Yes, the subspace measure is defined on the trace $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I am not clear why $\mathcal{M}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Since $f$ is measurable, then **if** $\{0\}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $\mathcal{M}$ is a borel subset too. However, I am not sure $\{0\}$ is Borel measurable.

Comment: Back to the trace, I guess the borel sigma algebra on $\mathcal{M}$ contains the trace, i.e.
$$
\text{trace}_{\mathcal{M}}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)) \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{M})
$$
so that one can define the restriction of $\pi$ onto $(\mathcal{M}, \text{trace}_{\mathcal{M}}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)))$
$$
\pi|_{\mathcal{M}}(A) = \pi(A) \qquad \forall \, A\in \text{trace}_{\mathcal{M}}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)).
$$
Then $\pi|_{\mathcal{M}}$ is on $(\mathcal{M}, \text{trace}_{\mathcal{M}}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)))$ rather than $(\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{M}))$

Comment: At this point, we can actually extend $\pi|_{\mathcal{M}}$ as you suggested by defining
$$
\pi^*(A) = \pi|_{\mathcal{M}}(A\cap \mathcal{M}) \qquad A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)).
$$
Now $\pi^*$ is a measure on $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$.

Comment: $\{0\}$ is a closed set and closed sets are Borel as the completementbof open sets.

Comment: I have one more question related to this, for simplicity consider $\mathcal{C}=\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $\pi\ll \mathcal{H}$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is the Hausdorff measure on $\mathcal{M}$, that is $\pi$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Hausdorff measure. 

Then can I say that $\pi^* \ll \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ and $\pi^*$ is the extension of $\pi$ onto $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ as defined above?

Comment: Notice that $\mathcal{M}$ has dimension $n-m$

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Hausdorff measures; sorry.